# Choosing randomly between functions in Flash ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, kinect

We have hooked up a Kinect to Flash and using it to control an avatar inside Flash, then we  added another player in the Kinect and control the avatar using both players. One arm and one leg each. Now the problem comes. We want to mix it up during a game we are making.

So, we need a function on a timer that randomly selects an arm and a leg from each player. But we gotta be sure that we don't get both arms/legs from one player or vice versa.

Any good ideas on how to approach this?

We thought about using the Array and using several math functions in order to get the final result, but I was hoping there was a better way?

We are using an XML SocketServer to get the x and y coordinates from Kinect into Flash, then we use this code for the different player limbs:

```
//Player 1 Hand Right
p1hr_x = property.MESSAGE.(@NAME == "player1_right_hand_x").ARGUMENT.@VALUE;
p1hr_y = property.MESSAGE.(@NAME == "player1_right_hand_y").ARGUMENT.@VALUE;
var p1hr_xa:int = p1hr_x*stage.stageWidth;
var p1hr_ya:int = p1hr_y*stage.stageHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you'll be switching to creatures with more than two arms and two legs, you might as well use really simple code for that specific situation:

```
if (Math.random() < 0.5)
{
    player1.arm = character.lArm;
    player2.arm = character.rArm;
}
else
{
    player1.arm = character.rArm;
    player2.arm = character.lArm;
}
```

And the same for the legs. It might not be very elegant, this code doesn't have to be, because it is only run occasionally (at the start of a round). You only need something more flexible, if you ever decide to support an arbitrary number of players or allow players to control different kind of avatars (different number of legs, etc).

Comment: Thanks, we're gonna try it out. Kinda newbies when it comes to Flash, so simple works excellent for us. ;-)